# How to use "as" with "or" in one sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, as

I would like to express two different points in one sentence using "as" and "or".

In my area of study, we have an independent case, that is the two variables are independent. I built a new method, and I already know that my variables are independent. However, I would like to test the performance of my method. The result of my method was very close (for some variables) to the independence case while it was exactly independent for other variables.

I would like to express my found in one sentence, as follows:

The result of this method is treated as, or very close to, independence case.

I feel my sentence is wrong because:

1. If I need to write the first part of the sentence, then I need to express it as follows:

*The result of this method is treated as an independent case.*

2. If I need to write only the send part, then I need to write this:

*The result of this method is treated to be very close to an independent case*.

How can I express my sentence is a correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the meaning of your sentence is not clear (how **a method** can be an **independent case**) you might construct it this way:

> This method is treated either as an independent case or very close to one.

It might be easier to supply a better answer if you could give the context of what you want to say.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the result of the method. I will edit it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have edit my question to make it so clear.

Comment: @Maryam  Are you trying to say that the result given by the method is unusual or unique or exceptional or unreliable? What do you mean by **an independent case**?

Comment: In my area of study, we have an independent case, that is the two variables are independent. I built a new method, and I already know that my variables are independent. However, I would like to test the performance of my method. The result of my method was very close (for some variables) to the independence case while it was exactly independent for other variables.

Comment: @Maryam Now I understand but it's a specialised area in which I'm out of my depth. Even so, inserting **The result of ....** into my answer seems to be appropriate.